# How can I use Core Data Objects outside of a managed object context?

Tags: core-data

I would like to use Core Data Managed Objects outside of a managed object context. I've seen other threads on this site that say you should never do this, but here's my issue:

I have a 'Feed' object and a 'story' object. Feed is like an RSS feed, and story is like a single story from that feed. I have the ability to bookmark feeds, and I use Core Data to persist those, but I when I download stories from a feed, I don't want to insert those stories into the managed object context. The only way to create my objects, however, is by doing this:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Which means that it will be persisted at the next save event.

I don't want these objects to be persisted until the user selects them.

I tried defining a "TransientStory" and a "PersistentStory" with a protocol called "Story" that both of them implement, but it's a nightmare. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can create these objects and just not insert them in the context:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedContext];
ManagedObjectClass *volatileObject = [[ManagedObjectClass alloc] initWithEntity:entity
                                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

And if you want to save it you just insert it to the context:

```
[managedContext insertObject:volatileObject];
```

(if you forget to add it, it will give you a dangling object error when you try to save it in the context)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `NSManagedObjectContext` with an in-memory store.  Then you can put your transient objects into this context, and they won't be persisted.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSBundle mainBundle]]]; // though you can create a model on the fly (i.e. in code)
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]     initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];

NSError *err;

// add an in-memory store. At least one persistent store is required
if([psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&err] == nil) {
  NSLog(@"%@",err);
}

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
```

If you did want to then persist them, just move them to the proper store afterwards, or merge the context.

Alternatively, if you're eventually going to put them into that context anyway (i.e. you just don't want them appearing in lists until they're saved), then just set `setIncludesPendingChanges` to `NO` in your `NSFetchRequest`.